# Making the identification $\tau M\approx TM\oplus (TM\odot TM)$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, tensor-products

Given a smooth manifold $M$, there is a vector bundle over $M$, denoted $\tau M$, known as the second-order tangent bundle. The fiber $\tau_mM$ at $m\in M$ is the collection of linear operators $A_m:C^\infty(M)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that satisfy

$$ A_m(f^3)=3f(m)A_m(f^2)-3f^2(m)A_m(f) $$

for each $f\in C^\infty(M)$. It isn't too hard to show that each section of $\tau M$ is locally of the form

$$A_m=a^i(m)\partial_i+b^{ij}(m)\partial^2_{ij},$$

where $a^i$ and $b^{ij}$ are smooth functions, $b^{ij}=b^{ji}$, $\partial_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$, $\partial^2_{ij}=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^i\partial x^j}$, and I'm using the Einstein summation convention.

For each $m\in M$ There is a short exact sequence

$$T_mM\rightarrow \tau_m M\rightarrow T_mM\odot T_mM$$

where $\odot$ denotes the symmetric tensor product. The first arrow is the inclusion map that sends a vector at $m$ to its corresponding directional derivative operator $C^\infty(M)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. The second arrow is given by $A_m\mapsto \hat{A}_m$, where $\hat{A}_m$ is defined by the formula

$$ \hat{A}_m(\mathbf{d}_mf,\mathbf{d}_mg)=A_m(fg)-f(m) A_m(g)-g(m) A_m(f), $$

and $f,g\in C^\infty(M)$.

My question: One way to split the sequence, and thereby identify $\tau M$ with $TM\oplus(TM\odot TM)$, is to assign to each $m\in M$ a subspace $S_m\subset \tau_mM$ that is complementary to $T_mM\subset \tau_m M$. Is there a name for such an assignment?
I'd just like to know if there is an established name so that I can more easily search for what people already know about such things.

Comment: This is usually called a connection. This may be somewhat confusing, as there are other objects called connection (connections as certain first order differential operators, connections as certain lie-algebra-valued one-forms on principal bundles), but it all makes sense as all these things are equivalent to each other.

Comment: More precisely, specifying such a splitting is equivalent to specifying a *torsion-free* (aka *symmetric*) connection.

Comment: @MatthiasLudewig  Thank you. I thought it seemed very similar in spirit to the notion of a so-called Ehresmann connection. However, I didn't see how the details worked out because, in the case of the Ehresmann connection, the exact sequence is $V_eE\rightarrow T_eE\rightarrow T_{\pi(e)}B$, where $\pi:E\rightarrow B$ is some fiber bundle and $VE\subset TE$ is the vertical subbundle. I couldn't see how $\tau_m M$ plays the role of $T_eE$.

Comment: This bundle does not seem to be the same as the ones that are usually called higher order tangent bundles like here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.3111. Could you give a reference for the notion you are using?

Comment: @MichaelBächtold  Sure. I first saw this use of this terminology in this PHD thesis by Joan Andreu Lazaro Cami http://gmcnet.webs.ull.es/files/thesis/alazaro.pdf. See p. 33. The book "Global and Stochastic Analysis with Applications to Mathematical Physics" by Yuri E. Gliklikh also uses it. On page 66 of the book, there are a number of other references.

Comment: Thanks, maybe the notions do coincide. I'm not sure yet.

Comment: @MichaelBächtold I'm curious about this too. Lazaro Cami says that $\tau M$ is naturally a vector bundle over $M$ (which seems to make sense). Meanwhile, it looks like the arXiv paper you sent needs additional structure to give $T^2M$ a vector bundle structure.

Comment: Actually fibers of $\tau M$ and $T^2M$ have different dimensions, so they can't be the same. (Btw. the notation $T^2M$ is also used for the iterated tangent bundle $T(TM)$ so there is danger of confusion here.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given a connection on the tangent bundle, you can define the second covariant derivative $\nabla^2f$ by
$$ \nabla^2f[X, Y] := \partial_X\partial_Y f - \partial_{\nabla_X Y} f.$$
Then $\nabla^2f$ is a symmetric tensor *provided that $\nabla$ was torsion-free*, which Robert pointed out but I missed in the first moment.

(This is because
$$\nabla^2f[Y, X] = \partial_X\partial_Y f + \partial_{[Y, X]} f - \partial_{\nabla_Y, X} = \partial_X\partial_Y f  - \partial_{\nabla_X, Y}+ T(X, Y),$$
where $T$ is the torsion tensor of nabla.)

Now given such a torsion-free connection, you can associate to an element polynomial $p \in TM \odot TM$ the operator 
$$Pf = \langle p, \nabla^2 f\rangle.$$
This gives a splitting of your sequence, since the principal symbol of $P$ will be $p$ again.

Conversely, if $S: TM \odot TM \longrightarrow \tau M$ is such a splitting, set $\Gamma$ to be the projection onto $TM$ along the image of $S$ (i.e. $\Gamma = \iota^{-1}(\mathrm{id} - S \circ \pi)$ with $\pi:\tau M \longrightarrow TM \odot TM$ the projection). Then 
$$\nabla_X Y := \Gamma(\partial_X \partial_Y)$$
is a torsion-free connection.

Comment: I think we want a $\Gamma:\tau M\rightarrow TM$, right? Should it be $\Gamma=\iota^{-1}\circ(\text{id}-S\circ\pi)$, where $\iota:TM\rightarrow \iota(TM)\subset \tau M$ is the inclusion?

Comment: $\pi$ doesn't take values in $\tau M$; I think you might want $S\circ \pi$ instead of $\pi\circ S$?